# How do I separate the two "Built-In Audio" output devices to play to multiple devices?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have headphones connected to the 3.5mm out from my motherboard, as well as Digital Output  (optical) going to my DAC. When Digital Output is selected in the sound settings, everything works fine. But when I select the "Headphone" output, audio plays both to my headphones and to the DAC, at 100% volume. System volume control then will affect the headphone output, but not the Digital out.

pavucontrol shows only one Output Device, in either case. This issue is not present at all with my Nvidia displayport out.

What would be the best way for me to go about troubleshooting this?

Output of `pactl list | grep -A3 'Source #'`

```
Source #0
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor
    Description: Monitor of HDA NVidia Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
--
Source #1
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_input.usb-046d_HD_Pro_Webcam_C920_93AA627F-02.analog-stereo
    Description: HD Pro Webcam C920 Analog Stereo
--
Source #3
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_input.usb-Samson_Technologies_Samson_Q2U_Microphone-00.analog-stereo
    Description: Q2U handheld mic with XLR Analog Stereo
--
Source #5
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
    Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
--
Source #6
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_output.usb-Samson_Technologies_Samson_Q2U_Microphone-00.iec958-stereo.monitor
    Description: Monitor of Q2U handheld mic with XLR Digital Stereo (IEC958)
--
Source #13
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.iec958-stereo.monitor
    Description: Monitor of Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)
```

This seems to be a confusion between sources 5, 13, but not sure where to go from here.

Thanks for any assistance!